# What's the fastest, easiest, or most obvious way to clear cache and cookies from a site when it just redirects you to an error on a second site?

Tags: browser, authentication, cookies

My problem scenario is one that's played out thousands of times with only minor details varying.

I am using a web browser and I click a bookmark to "https://desired-site.example1.com/". I've used this site before, but my session is expired. The site sees my expired session and redirects my browser to "https://auth.example2.com/" (some auth provider like google, microsoft, etc.) with some basic facts from the expired session as parameters (username, return URI, etc.).

The problem is that there is something funny about my expired session. One way or another the request to auth.example2.com is garbled, and it results in a 4xx or 5xx error, and it won't just show a proper login form.

Fixing that "real" problem with buggy login sessions or error handling is out of scope for this question. Assume you have no special access and no support for example1.com or example2.com.

I clear cookies, cache etc. for auth.example2.com using my browser's built-in features, an add-on, or whatever.

I return to desired-site.example1.com. I am redirected to auth.example2.com and experience the same error message. My "fast, easy and obvious" options to clear cookies are all oriented towards auth.example2.com and example2.com.

What is the most practical way to get a fresh session on desired-site.example1.com when it always redirects to auth.example2.com?

I'll take answers for any browser. The ideal answer would be one a tech support person can trivially explain to a user, and ideally one the user can remember and re-use later.

Comment: Is the bookmark *actually* to `site.com` or is it to `site.com/inordinately long bit of code` (which is the one I often find on government sites & other badly coded, under-funded sites.) The second is easy. Manually delete the long bit.

Comment: I have experienced that and it's a good technique for that situation, but I've also had the problem with a  "site.com" link, with no dubious extra text to remove.

Answer (score 0):

In a situation where I just need the browser to "stay put" on desired-site.example1.com, I will go to the location bar (ctrl-L) and type a link like "desired-site.example1.com/deliberate-404-error-asdf", using autocomplete to start editing a previously visited link. The link can be anything on the same site, as long as it isn't a real page.

Instead of getting a bad redirect to the authentication system, most sites will just give a 404 error page. Since it's not an instant redirect, the browser's options to clear cookies and cache will be oriented to desired-site.example1.com.

After that, we can finally go back to the original link with a fresh opportunity to log in.

Comment: I think this is a weird solution that doesn't always work, but I asked the question because this is what I do all too often, now, and I feel like I'm breaking the rules or just missing a more obvious way to handle the situation. If I see someone else with the same problem, I am reluctant to give them such strange, specific advice.